# required field validator for telerik radio button

Tags: javascript, c#, telerik, radio-button

How can I set required field validator for telerik radio button? I want to set required field validator on button click "BtnSave"? Please help!

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="radio_male" runat="server" ToggleType="Radio" AutoPostBack="false" GroupName="gender"
    Text="Male" Skin="Metro">
    <ToggleStates>
        <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadioChecked"></telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
        <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadio"></telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
    </ToggleStates>
</telerik:RadButton>

<telerik:RadButton ID="radio_female" runat="server" ToggleType="Radio" AutoPostBack="false" GroupName="gender"
    Text="Female" Skin="Metro">
    <ToggleStates>
        <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadioChecked"></telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
        <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadio"></telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
    </ToggleStates>
</telerik:RadButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can not directly apply validator control on radbutton but we can achieve given requirement by using below code snippet.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ClientClicked(sender, args) {
                var txt = $("#<%=radio_txt.ClientID%>");
                txt.val("test");
            }
        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
            <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
            </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
            <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server"></telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
            <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadWindowManager>
            <telerik:RadButton ID="radio_male" runat="server" ToggleType="Radio" AutoPostBack="false" GroupName="gender"
                Text="Male" Skin="Metro" OnClientClicked="ClientClicked">

                <ToggleStates>
                    <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadioChecked"></telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
                    <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadio"></telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
                </ToggleStates>
            </telerik:RadButton>

            <telerik:RadButton ID="radio_female" runat="server" ToggleType="Radio" AutoPostBack="false" GroupName="gender"
                Text="Female" Skin="Metro" OnClientClicked="ClientClicked">
                <ToggleStates>
                    <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadioChecked"></telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
                    <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadio"></telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
                </ToggleStates>
            </telerik:RadButton>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Gender" ControlToValidate="radio_txt" ErrorMessage="required !!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="radio_txt" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Gender"></asp:TextBox>

            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Click me" ValidationGroup="Gender" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried to copy your code but it didn't work since my project doesn't have jQuery in it. So instead of using asp TextBox, I used RadTextBox and Telerik js to set a value in the textbox. Thanks again.